# Gitlab coverage badge with dynamic pipeline name

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project on gitlab.org with the following settings:

1. Default branch is `master`, MRs are set to fast-forward only.
2. A merge request (with a source branch different from `master`) triggers a pipeline, which includes a coverage report.
3. The coverage is (or will be eventually) correctly shown for the pipeline, which is assigned to whatever branch name was used for the MR.
4. The merge request is merged (fast forward, so the new `master` commit is exactly the same that was tested with the pipeline).
5. A new pipeline is triggered by the change in `master`, but this one is mostly a "deploy" pipeline, no tests are run, no coverage is computed.

I would like to show the coverage in a badge, but the problem I find is that the branch name I should use is changing for every MR. So what could I do? How can I figure out which MR triggered a `master` update? If I could do that, maybe the `master` pipeline could read the coverage from the MR pipeline and report it as its own. Any other solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any downsides to re-triggering the tests/coverage on `master`? (minus the time cost)

Comment: @Rekovni Time and resource cost is an issue, especially with limited CI minutes or with specific runners (which would then be hijacked to run redundant jobs instead of testing other branches/MRs). Pipeline maintenance is also a concern: the jobs run in MR pipelines and in `master` pipelines are quite different, copying a job (and its dependencies) from MR to `master` pipeline is possible, but not quite what I'm looking for.